# How to save information in a nested dictionary using forloops

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested-loops, nested-lists

I am practicing how to become better at working with dictionaries in python. For the sake of practice I'm trying to write a program that reads information about people from a file, and then store the information in a nested dictionary like this `{'key':value, {gender:male_or_female} }`

**The data file looks like**

```
Bob, 35, Male
George, 53, Male
Karen, 67, Female
Jamie, 20, Female
Aisha, 12, Female
Maria, 50, Female
Rolf, 16, Male
Ali, 90, Male
```

**The code I have written so far goes like**

```
def extract_person_data(filename):
    dicti = {}

    infile = open(filename)

    for line in infile:
        words = line.split(",")
        name = words[0]
        age = words[1]
        gender = words[2]
        dicti[name] = age
        dicti["Gender"] = gender
    infile.close()

    return dicti

print(extract_person_data("people.txt"))
```

**The program outputs:**

```
{'Bob': ' 35', 'Gender': ' Male', 'George': ' 53', 'Karen': ' 67', 'Jamie': ' 20', (...)}
```

Note that `'Gender': 'Male` only appears in the first list item. In other words, it returns kind of what I want, but not quite.

**My questions is**

How can assign a nested dictionary into each one of the main list items like `{'key':value, {gender:male_or_female} }`?

I hope there is someone who is kind enough to provide a rookie who is eager to learn with a solution and some explanation.

All help is massively appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think you really want is to create a `list` of elements, each of which is a `dict` with key value pairs of the data of each person:

```py
def extract_person_data(filename):
    result = []

    infile = open(filename)

    for line in infile:
        words = line.split(",")
        name = words[0]
        age = words[1]
        gender = words[2]
        dicti = {'name':name, 'age':age, 'Gender': gender}
        result.append(dicti)
    infile.close()

    return result

print(extract_person_data("people.txt"))
```

There are a few improvements I would suggest.

Splitting the line using `", "` to remove the leading space. Also `.strip()` the line to remove the trailing linefeed.

Then it is better to use `with open(...` to ensure the file is always closed.

```py
def extract_person_data(filename):
    result = []

    with open(filename) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            words = line.strip().split(", ")
            name = words[0]
            age = words[1]
            gender = words[2]
            dicti = {'name':name, 'age':age, 'Gender': gender}
            result.append(dicti)

    return result
```

Comment: @fredericoamigo Since you're asking about dictionaries, one way to format your data could be `{'Bob': {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 35', 'gender': 'male'}` and you repeat for however many people you have. However, this will not work if you have multiple people named 'bob' as they would be overwritten. I think the better solution is what @quamrana has posted, where you create a list of dictionaries instead. Example being `[{'name': 'bob', 'age': 35, 'gender': 'male'}, [{'name': 'george', 'age': 53, 'gender': 'male'}]`

Comment: @quamrana: Yeah I agree, but the task I'm working on requires it to be a nested dictionary. Like I wrote in the description: it's for the sake of practice:-)

Comment: You should update your required output to specify an example of a nested `dict`.

Comment: @quamrana: Actually, when I read the task I'm given more closely, I actually think your solution might meet the requirements after all :-)